# C++ Understanding the Initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have been going through a piece of code.
Can someone explain this line of code. What is this doing?

`dt = (dt < temp ? dt : temp)`

Looking for a response.

Comment: It's a use of the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) -- it is not "the ternary operator".

Comment: This is using the [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) to implement a manual `min()` operation. It sets `dt` to itself if `dt` is less than `temp`, and sets `dt` to `temp` if `temp` is less than or equal to `dt`.

Comment: @paddy I agree "conditional operator" is a more useful name, but "the ternary operator" is also correct. C++ (like C) has exactly one ternary operator; namely, the conditional operator, so "the" is fine.

Comment: @aschepler Actually, since C++20, there is *another* ternary operator: `<=>`.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, the `<=>` operator is binary: it forms an expression from exactly two subexpressions. Sometimes its result type is "ternary" with three possible values, which could cause some confusion, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using the [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) to implement a manual `min()` operation. The code is roughly equivalent to this:

```c
if (dt < temp)
    dt = dt
else
    dt = temp;
```

It is setting `dt` to the value of itself if `dt < temp` is true, otherwise it is setting `dt` to the value of `temp` if `temp <= dt` is true.

IOW, it is the equivalent to doing `dt = min(dt, temp);`

Answer (score 0):

Hey there this syntax is called ternary operator

This is your condition

```
(dt<temp)
```

If your condition is true then this will run.

```
? dt
```

and if condition doesn't meet the requirements then the statement after ":" will run.

```
: temp
```

Example:

```
int time = 20;
String result = (time < 18) ? "Good day." : "Good evening.";
printf(result);
```

If time is less than 18 then it will print Good day and if it is not less than 18 then this will print Good evening.

You can learn more from here:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/